# Magento 2 Error message when flushing cache

Tags: php, caching, magento2

I'm running Magento 2.0.7. When I'm in the backend and I try to flush the cache using "Flush Megento Cache" or selecting all cache folders and click refresh I get a white pack with the below error:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 707031421789

The website continues to function, and Magento recognises that cache is cleared as the notification disappears. But it's annoying and I don't know if its actually clearing all cache or not

The error report shows the below detail:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:166:"Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 508";i:1;s:8000:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'is_file() expec...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 508, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php(508): is_file('/var/www/vhosts...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php(222): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_cleanNew('matchingTag', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php(465): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->clean('matchingTag', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Core.php(98): Zend_Cache_Core->clean('matchingTag', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(79): Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->clean('matchingTag', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(91): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->clean('matchingTag', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(73): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->clean('matchingTag', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(91): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->clean('all', Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Logger.php(47): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->clean('all', Array, 'all')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/FlushSystem.php(20): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Logger->clean()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/FlushSystem/Interceptor.php(25): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem->execute()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->execute()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#25 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/FlushSystem/Interceptor.php(40): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#33 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#34 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#35 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#38 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#39 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 /var/www/vhosts/tbfdirect.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#42 {main}";s:3:"url";s:107:"/admin_bb88q1/admin/cache/flushSystem/key/3ea674fce8bdcfd57376928bc89c1f15f7e9664b76cf642ea78f5d76fe4a90da/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

This refers to line 508 of file.php which has the below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've long since solved this but for posterity I have just fixed a very similar problem by deleting the contents of **var/cache**. Since you are trying to clear caches anyway this should have no side effects.